# Labview: I can't read the voltage from more than one channel (DAQmx read)

Tags: labview, daq-mx

I have a SCB 68A connector from National Instruments and I want to read out the open voltage from it. So I used the example code provided by National Instruments (https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-28502):

[image]

I got 5 mV which is a reasonable value (I measured the noise signal with an oscilloscope). Now I want to read out the noise signal from few channels. So I sightly changed the VI (according to the documentation I need to create an array of channels and flatten them):
[image]

But now I read out approximately 200 mV on both channels (and one of them is the same as in the first VI). It doesn't make any sense.

What am I doing wrong?

I want the user to be able to choose the channels, so I can't just write "Dev1/ai0:4".

Edit: I'm using the DAQ 14.0.0.

Edit 2: 1) There is nothing connected to the deivce - I just want to read out the noise signal. 
        2) I'm using the connector in the MIO with the disabled temperature sensor mode (the default configuration).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are observing charge injection from the DAQ device's multiplexer. Connect each `aiN` terminal to `aignd` and you will be able to measure the noise of the DAQ device.

## Charge Injection

Most NI DAQ boards have a single analog to digital converter (ADC) and provide multiple input channels by using a multiplexer (MUX) to switch the input of the ADC to the different analog input terminals `ai0`, `ai1`, etc:
[image: Sample DAQ System]

As [NI explains](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/4E9B8B3F8FD3A31B862562B5004EA1D9), when the DAQ device's multiplexer moves from one channel to the next, it can *introduce a small charge on each channel*. Since the open channel *does not have a path* for this charge to dissipate, the voltage of the channel will increase. This can also cause the channel to rail, slowly floating up to the maximum input voltage (usually 10 V).

## Characterizing Noise

You can determine the noise of each component in your system by:

1. Measuring the noise of the DAQ device
2. Measuring the noise of the DAQ device and terminal block
3. Subtracting the DAQ device noise (step 1) from the system noise (step 2)

When you're finished, the value from step 1 is the noise of the DAQ device, and the value from step 3 is the noise of the SCB-68.

To measure the noise of an electric path, there must be a complete circuit for the ADC to sample. For step 1, connect each `aiN` terminal to `aignd` and run your VI. For step 2, connect the terminal block to the DAQ device, disconnect the sensor, and connect the terminal block's channel terminals to its ground terminal and run your VI.

## Minimizing Noise

In addition to charge injection, noise can be introduced to a DAQ system from [several sources](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/3344/en/#toc4), including the environment. Open terminals act like small antennas and receive radiated energy from other electronics, lights, and the AC mains.

The link also outlines how to find and minimize noise, but the gist is:

1. Systematically identify the sources of the noise.
2. Remove sources of noise that aren't necessary for your measurements.
3. Depending on the nature and source of the remaining noise, use appropriate shielding, cabling, and terminal configuration.
4. Over-sample and average the signal.

Comment: OK, thanks for the explanation. But right now I don't want to measure the noise, I just want to understand why I have such a huge difference between reading out one channel and two channels. You wrote that the multiplexer can "introduce a small charge on each channel". But is switching from 5 mV to 200 mV a small change? It's not a rhetorical question, I'm really curious (I don't have much experience with electronics).

Comment: I am confused by your word choices. Please be more accurate. In your question, you say *"I want to read out the noise signal"* but now you say *"I don't want to measure the noise"*. To your question, *"is 200mV a small charge?"* I will say this: open terminals suffer from more than charge injection. Depending on the environment and cabling, the system might exhibit significant noise. I've added a new section describing that and how to minimize it.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion - as I wrote in the chat, when I said "noise signal", I meant "the open voltage". Thanks for the extra section. I'll have a lok at it.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look on the links below: 
http://forums.ni.com/t5/Multifunction-DAQ/How-to-use-DAQmx-Read-to-measure-multiple-analog-channels/td-p/2620949

http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/A3A05920BF915F1486256D210069BE49

There is the complete solution to your question.

Comment: My problem that creating multiple channels doesn't work properly, although theoretically I know how to do it.  And on the first webpage it is explained how to do it. I already implemented that in the piece of code I showed you. The second link isn't helpful at all - the described syntax is  automatically created from the array by the DAQmx Flatten Channel String VI. And it still doesn't work (at least for me).

Comment: So you declare, you found bug on LabVIEW?

Comment: Khachik Sahakyan, I hope I didn't. Someone would have found it earlier. This is not a new VI. Did I?

Comment: What is the DAQ version you use?

Comment: I'm using DAQ 14.0.0.

Comment: I am more about your Data Acquisition device model from NI

Comment: This is a  SCB 68A connector (http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/pl/nid/210777).

Comment: Please add more information:

(1) what is the DAQmx device (the SCB-68A is a terminal block, it doesn't have any ADCs on it). In other words, what model is "Dev1"?

(2) what is the configuration of the SCB-68A? That terminal block has several input modes configured with switches on the unit. See page 12 of its user manual: http://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/375865a.pdf

Comment: 1) There is nothing connected to the connector- I just want to read out the noise signal. 2) I'm using the connector in the MIO with the disabled temperature sensor mode (the default configuration).

Comment: user2738748 where do you connected the cable from SCB-68A?

How you has connected it to your computer?

Comment: And a cable provided by NI ().763507-02 type X2).

Comment: I repeat my question: what NI device model is "Dev1"?

Comment: None. It's going to be a magnetic field sensor, but I haven't connected it yet. I just want to measure the noise (with no instrument attached).

Comment: If it's not connected to an NI device, why do expect DAQmx Read to give you meaningful voltages in your VI?

Comment: I'd say reasonable , not meaningful, which is almost zero (and 5 mV is almost zero) since there is (almost ) no current.  When I have only one channel, I get the 5 mV, but when I have two channels, I get 200 mV - this is a huge difference and it means that there must be something wrong.

Comment: If Dev1 is not connected to the SCB-68, then DAQmx Read is returning the open voltage at Dev1's unconnected terminals. You're not measuring the noise introduced by the SCB-68 *at all* because there is no electrical connection between them. If you want to see the noise of the analog channels on Dev1, short each analog input terminal to `aignd` and run your VI. If you want to see the noise of both Dev1 **and** the SCB-68, connect them together and short the SCB-68's terminals to its ground pin and run your VI. If you want to see the noise from just the SCB-68, short its pins and use a scope.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88136/discussion-between-joe-friedrichsen-and-user2738748).